# SP2010 Crawl component Increase

Tags: service-application

In my SP 2010 Search, i am using only one Crawl component 
but crawl time is took very long..so can i add one more crawl component ?(my searchable item is 8 lak+)

At what situation crawl component should increase ?..Please tel me the scenario.

Note: 2 app,2 wef and 1 sql(culster).app1 is acting as a search server

Answer (score 1):

Crawling and indexing are I/O and CPU intensive; adding more machines increases the crawl/index throughput linearly.

However, You should note that adding more crawlers may not help if :

- Crawl rate is low due to IOPS bottlenecks in the search crawl
  subsystem.
- Crawl rate is low due to slow repository responsiveness.

Please refer to this article for more details : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg750251.aspx